# How to achieve following on placeholder image in ImageView Android like Pinterest?

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I have used Picasso in my Android Application which has many images. Its working and looking good. I am trying to make UI more of simple and user friendly. I have placeholder for my imageviews before actual image loads. But its white color. I want to placeholder image depending on main color of image like pinterest.

Pinterest placeholder images before main image loads. Following screenshot:

[image]

And after image loads it shows proper image based on main background color shown for placeholder:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve in Picasso library provided by Square or whats the way to achieve.

Please help.

Comment: Try to do some search over here : http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: i researched did not find any specific information. They have option for placeholder but doesnt specific on what i want to achieve

Comment: @user3549273 didnt find that time and left it after that

Answer (score 1):

Bit late but for other readers that want to accomplish a similar thing, I'll just leave this here. I don't know how Pinterest did/does it, probably developed their own implementation. But Google updated the v7 support library with 'Palette' which is a new API which allows you to extract prominent colours from images when provided with an Image Bitmap.

**Edit:** Something I just realised that this probably doesn't help for placeholders since you need an image to actually get colours from! So my best guess is that Pinterest does the colour extraction from the server and includes the colour in the (presumably) JSON response that is sent to the client.

I haven't used it much myself but it works quite well from what I've seen/read. You can read up more about it at these two places:

[Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html)
[Tutorial/Explanation (Willow Tree Apps)](http://www.willowtreeapps.com/blog/palette-the-new-api-for-android/)

Comment: if i want to use it as placeholder i need to keep images for each color

Comment: How could you extract colors of an image which is not loaded yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can only do that by saving the prominent color from the image while saving it in your database & then retrieving it for later use.

https://pypi.org/project/extcolors/ is a very easy to use python library that extracts the colors for you given an image.

Or you could you https://github.com/woltapp/blurhash a library that'll give you this.

[image: Easy library]
[image: This too, it's easy]

Both ways, you'll have to first save the BlurHash or The color as a metadata in your database, and then when the user requests the data, you'll send either of those and display them till the data is fully downloaded.